# Getting JS to add all fields together while replacing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to simulate a game through JS and HTML. My problem is that when I try and make it add the values it won't process it and change the value.

http://jsfiddle.net/rwybp41e/1/

I am trying to add all the Points and place them in the div with a class `TotalPoints`.

I have also tried using:

`var div = document.getElementsByClassName('TotalPoints');
div.innerHTML = sum;`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `each` to loop over all the `.Points` and set the value inside `.TotalPoints` using `text`.

```
var total = 0;
$('.Points').each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
});
$('.TotalPoints').text(total);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/rwybp41e/2/

Comment: I'm planning on making the values of the points change over time so a value will come in from a MYSQL db and show one by one everytime I click. Will this value update or will it need re-calculating?

Comment: @BradlySpicer Recalculation is required after each new value addition

Comment: anyway I can do this automatically with Jquery? Check every one second or something?

Comment: You can use `setInterval` and call the function after given interval

Comment: Hey @Tushar.

I've just tried doing this, for some reason it's still not executing. I've done it EXACTLY the same as the JSfiddle. I've done this into pastebin just for confirmation: http://pastebin.com/CWeYJQUa

Comment: @BradlySpicer Wrap above code in `document.ready` method of jQuery

Comment: Hi, if you have to use native js then just add another ID to the div containing the totalpoints class like here: http://jsfiddle.net/rwybp41e/7/

Answer (score 2):

Your targetting the wrong ID's and classes in your fiddle and you didn't include the jQuery library.

HTML:

```
<div id="TotalPoints"></div>
<div class="total-points">0</div>
```

CSS:

```
.total-points {
    padding: 8px;
    //background: blue;
    width: 20px;
    float:right;
    margin-top: 4px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
// Add all "Points" class together  

var sum = 0;
$('.Points').each(function () {
    sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
});
$('.total-points').text(sum);
```

Here is a working demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/rwybp41e/3/

Answer (score 1):

Since the data you're interested in is a reduction of a collection of points to a single total, you can calculate the total more functionally using `Array.reduce`:

```
$('.TotalPoints').text($('.Points')
                .toArray()
                .reduce(function (agg, point) { 
                    return agg + parseInt($(point).text(), 10); 
                }, 0));
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/rwybp41e/4/